salesman problem with knapsack problem in R
I want to optimize the order distribution prose by combining the salesman problem with the knapsack problem in R language using linear programming. Here is the code:
install.packages("lpSolve")
library(lpSolve)

# Data
cities <- c("Warsaw", "Toruń", "Wrocław", "Łódź", "Radom", "Skierniewice", "Częstochowa", "Wieluń", "Włocławek")
boxes <- c(100, 50, 75, 105, 30, 35, 115, 40, 85)
values <- c(100, 50, 75, 105, 30, 35, 115, 40, 85)
vehicle_capacity <- 544
distances <- matrix(c(0, 162, 230, 191, 58, 143, 112, 76, 65, 178,
                      162, 0, 259, 351, 136, 105, 78, 218, 244, 206,
                      230, 259, 0, 359, 181, 314, 201, 288, 289, 64,
                      191, 351, 359, 0, 223, 359, 294, 247, 133, 346,
                      58, 136, 181, 223, 0, 112, 199, 208, 259, 165,
                      143, 105, 314, 359, 112, 0, 112, 168, 184, 146,
                      112, 78, 201, 294, 199, 112, 0, 69, 233, 234,
                      76, 218, 288, 247, 208, 168, 69, 0, 233, 234,
                      65, 244, 289, 133, 259, 184, 233, 233, 0, 64,
                      178, 206, 64, 346, 165, 146, 234, 234, 64, 0), nrow = length(cities), byrow = TRUE)

# Number of cities
n <- length(cities)

# Linear programming problem
lp <- lp("max",
         c(rep(0, n), rep(1, n^2)),  # variables: number of boxes and route
         rbind(matrix(c(rep(1, n), rep(0, n^2)), nrow = 1),  # sum of boxes constraint
               matrix(c(rep(0, n), kronecker(matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = 1), diag(n))), ncol = n^2)),  # vehicle capacity constraint
         c(vehicle_capacity, rep(1, n)),  # constraints
         "<=",
         c(vehicle_capacity, rep(1, n)),
         all.bin = TRUE)

# Optimal value
cost <- lp$objval

# Route
routes <- matrix(lp$solution[n+1:length(lp$solution)], nrow = n, ncol = n)

# City indices in the route
indices <- c(1, which(routes[1, ] == 1), 1)

# Displaying results
cat("Route:")
cat(cities[indices], sep = " -> ")
cat("\nValue:", sum(values * routes), "\n")


I am getting following error:
Error in rbind(matrix(c(rep(1, n), rep(0, n^2)), nrow = 1), matrix(c(rep(0,  :
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(c(rep(0, n), kronecker(matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = 1),  :
data length [738] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [10]
what am I doing wrong? is such a solution even possible in r?

The problem is solvable in R in my opinion. Have you looked at the arguments to rbind and checked which argument has different ncol than you expected? (As a side note, the lpSolveAPI package is also an good option for this kind of problems.)
